# ggplot lwd overriding legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bit of a coding issue. I have a MWE below:

```
df <- data.frame(year=seq(1961,2013,1), group1=rnorm(53), group2=rnorm(53))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=group1, linetype="group1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=group2, linetype="group2"))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=group1, linetype="group1"), lwd=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=group2, linetype="group2"))
```

`p` produces a very standard looking graph with no issues:

[image]

However, when I try to change the linewidth in `p1`, of one of the `geom_line`, this distorts the legend as such:

[image]

The dotted aspect of the line remains the same but the lined segment is being affected by the `lwd=1.5` from the first line.

Is there an error/shortcoming in my approach to this problem or a larger issue at play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a nice legend with different linetypes and linewidths then you should convert your data to long format, map `group` on both `linetype` and `lwd` aestehtics and set the `lwd` manually using `scale_size_manual`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(year=seq(1961,2013,1), group1=rnorm(53), group2=rnorm(53))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "group") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=value, linetype = group, lwd = group)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1.5, .5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>